# Classify custom date string as date in AWS Glue Crawler

Tags: glue-crawler

Is there a way to convince an AWS Glue Crawler to parse the following formats in a json file correctly?

- `2022-10-18T09:53:48.4327277Z` -> datetime
- `2022-09-01 06:46:58.0` -> datetime
- `2022-10-16` -> date only

Currently those fields are all identified as `string` fields.

Example json:

```
{
    "Header": {
        "isoDateTime": "2022-10-18T09:53:48.4327277Z"
    },
    "Data": {
        "dateOnly": "2022-10-16",
        "dateTime": "2022-10-17 02:59:00.0"
    }
}
```